# Analyze performance issues, client, server, and database without source code?

Tags: sql-server, performance, windows-server-2012-r2

I work in a support and have now found performance problems from a customer. There is a Windows client application where the customer works in that communicate with a Windows Server and a MS SQL database. I have access to the client computer, windows server and database server but not the source code. The client works good when I test it on the Windows server (good performance or just luck).

How can I find out where the problem is? I have run MS SQL profile and found nothing and I have looked in the Windows event viewer, same there. I have looked in Windows task manager -> performance but I think it's hard to see if the data I see is good or bad.

How can I find out if the problem is on the client, server, database server, network and so on?

Comment: Without access to the code you options are more memory, faster hard drives or ssd, bigger CPU all of which is really a waste of money.

Comment: How do I know if there they should add more RAM? Windows task manager likes to use almost all your RAM even if you have a lot.

Comment: Windows performance counters. However this is really overkill. Can you access the SQL server from Enterprise manager?

Comment: What language? Did you try to decompile the app? Use `Resource-Monitor`or `Performance-Monitor` for analysis. Checked network (e.g. ping database-server)? Windows is using free ram to cache hdd-data, It' s availible if needed ( see Resource-Monitor).

Comment: MS SQL Management Studio? Yes I have access to that and the SQL/database Server.